# PlaySpec test passing even though the result doesn't match

Tags: asynchronous, scalatest, playframework-2.6

I have written the following spec. Surprisingly it passes even though the result doesn't match

code snippet

```
  val controller = new UserController(mockUserRepository,mockControllerComponents,mockSilhouette)
  //val request = FakeRequest[AnyContentAsJson]("POST", "/ws/users/signup").withJsonBody(Json.parse("""{"bad": "field"}"""))//FakeRequest(POST,"/ws/users/signup").withJsonBody(Json.parse("""{"bad":"field"}"""));
  val request = FakeRequest("POST","ws/users/signup")
  println("sending request",request)
  //val result = controller.someMethod()
  val result = controller.signupUser(request)

  Await.result(result,Duration("10 secs"))
  result.map(response => {
    println("response from controller:"+response)
    response mustBe play.api.mvc.Results.BadRequest
  })
```

console prints
`(sending request,POST ws/users/signup)`

print in controller. `(received request,POST ws/users/signup)`

Controller returns `200OK` but I am matching it with `BadRequest`. Still the test passes!
`response from controller:Result(200, Map())`

I suspect that I am not matching the result correctly. I am doing `response mustBe play.api.mvc.Results.BadRequest`. I know that `response` is `Results` but `BadRequest` is `Status`. But I don'w know how else to match and also why the test doesn't fail. I also tried following and can see the the values are different but even then the test passes.

```
  println("response from controller:"+response.header.status+" compared with "+play.api.mvc.Results.BadRequest.header.status)
        response.header.status mustBe play.api.mvc.Results.BadRequest.header.status
```

console print - `response from controller:200 compared with 400`

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509708/scala-play-framework-how-to-unit-test-async-controllers#answer-44510936) is a related answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing members of [`Helpers`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/fd402ccdfd9e74a0a4af0a6020247e0fbeacbc60/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L603) object like so

```
import play.api.test.Helpers._
```

gives access to various utility methods to [extract](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/fd402ccdfd9e74a0a4af0a6020247e0fbeacbc60/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L287) results from `Future[Result]` in tests. For example, `Helpers.status` can be used to extract status code like so:

```
val result: Future[Result] = controller.signupUser(request)
status(result) mustBe BAD_REQUEST
```

Another option is to use `whenReady` from [ScalaFutures](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/concurrent/ScalaFutures.html):

```
val result: Future[Result] = controller.signupUser(request)
whenReady(result) { _.header.status mustBe BAD_REQUEST }
```

Another option is to extend [`AsyncWordSpec`](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing) and then you can map over the `Future` like so:

```
val result: Future[Result] = controller.signupUser(request)
result.map(_.header.status mustBe BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thanks again Mario. But I don't understand why my code didn't work.